# Android 6.0 App Not Loading Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-6.0-marshmallow

I recently updated Android Studio and all associated support libraries, and my application is not progressing passed the first screen.

The first screen is a basic LoadingActivity that checks the authentication state of the user. If the user is authenticated, it progresses to the application, otherwise it goes to an activity prompting a sign up.

Here is the stack trace for my project:

```
  04-19 12:29:41.707 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-19 12:29:41.752 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/HyLog: I : openReadStream, /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, case (2)
04-19 12:29:41.752 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/HyLog: D: Wrong tag (927 : loadPreData() : frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/TypefaceHyFontManager.cpp)
04-19 12:29:41.752 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/HyLog: I : openReadStream, /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, case (2)
04-19 12:29:41.754 16877-16887/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-19 12:29:41.777 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sourcey.materialloginexample-1/lib/arm
04-19 12:29:41.949 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setLGNavigationBarColor : colors=0xff000000
04-19 12:29:41.949 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/PhoneWindow: [setLGNavigationBarColor] color=0x ff000000
04-19 12:29:42.104 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.sourcey.materialloginexample time:167295
04-19 12:29:42.144 16877-16939/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-19 12:29:42.171 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/PhoneWindow: notifyNavigationBarColor, color=0x: ff000000, token: android.view.ViewRootImplAO$WEx@3ec1bc9
04-19 12:29:42.225 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setLGNavigationBarColor : colors=0xff000000
04-19 12:29:42.225 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/PhoneWindow: [setLGNavigationBarColor] color=0x ff000000
04-19 12:29:42.231 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
04-19 12:29:42.411 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.sourcey.materialloginexample time:167603
04-19 12:29:42.476 16877-16939/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8916_32_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1__release_AU (I3193f6e94a)
                                                                              OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.00
                                                                              Build Date: 10/07/15 Wed
                                                                              Local Branch: 
                                                                              Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.6_rb1.1
                                                                              Local Patches: NONE
                                                                              Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
04-19 12:29:42.480 16877-16939/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-19 12:29:42.573 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@8611fd0 time:167764
04-19 12:29:42.573 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@8611fd0 time:167765
04-19 12:30:07.510 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
04-19 12:30:07.611 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
```

Loading Activity:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    final Firebase userRef = FirebaseUtil.FIREBASE.child("Users");
    final AuthData authData = userRef.getAuth();

    if (authData != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
  }
}
```

Build.Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sourcey.materialloginexample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.2'
  }
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.troychuinard.fanpolls">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".FanPollsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/fan_polls_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.firebase.ui.GoogleClientId"
            android:value="@string/google_client_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.firebase.ui.auth.twitter.TwitterPromptActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.firebase.ui.TwitterKey"
            android:value="@string/twitter_app_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.firebase.ui.TwitterSecret"
            android:value="@string/twitter_app_secret" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_poll"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoadingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Discussion_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_discussion_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PreviousActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_previous"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
       </application>

    </manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Add  a log statement in both if and else block of LoadingActivity and see which one of those are getting printed.

Comment: TypefaceHyFontManager class is missing from sdk...............

Comment: Why would that happen, and are you stating that's the only issue?

Comment: This line stuck out to me: 04-19 12:29:41.777 16877-16877/com.sourcey.materialloginexample W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sourcey.materialloginexample-1/lib/arm

Comment: Can you confirm whether the onCreate() method completes successfully? What happens if you put a call to `startActivity()` at the top of `onCreate()` and comment out `finish()`? Lastly, is Instant Run enabled in Android Studio?

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuilding? It solves similar problems for me.

Comment: I have tried cleaning....I also logged after both onCreate() and the if { } portion of my statement and it is logging both of them, that makes me believe it is an issue with the startActivity() method, I have also updated with an image to show that I have disabled Instant Run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post a copy of your Android Manifest:

"app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead."

Your Application Tag should be in Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:replace="label">
```

and / or Activity Tag should be in Android Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

The important thing is all activities must have themes using a variant of Theme.AppCompat.* when using AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I will give it a shot, I have updated to include my Manifest file

Comment: This does not appear to be working as my manifest already accounts for those changes...

Comment: Try changing to buildToolsVersion 23.0.2, and do a invalidate cache /restart. If this started happening after tools/studio update, these would be the two other things to check.

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't work. I do appreciate the help. I also tried loading a different activity and received this error, this Android update has caused nothing but problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728900/android-error-performing-stop-of-activity-that-is-not-resumed